# Want text element to align at the top of cell

Tags: html, css, html-email

What I'm trying to do is make the red arrows align with the text on the right in the *"In this issue, you can:"* section of http://jsfiddle.net/me42hfkw/. In other words, I want the `&rsaquo;`s of rows like

```
                                    <td valign="top" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                        <p valign="top" style="color:#FF0000;font-size:36px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:0;">&rsaquo;</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial;padding-bottom:20px;">
                                        <p style="color:#666666;line-height:18px;margin-top:0;">Learn about the IT and business trends driving walk-up service centers.</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

to be aligned at the top of their cell. I can't figure out why it's not working; for I was able to make it work on http://jsfiddle.net/qprc69z1/. What am I missing?

This is for an HTML email, by the way, so that I need to use as primitive of styles as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/me42hfkw/1/

You can decrease the `line height` of your `p` tag to adjust the position of the text. With a font-size as large as you're using there is a lot of white space to account for. Decreasing the line height will eliminate that white space.

The difference between the fiddle's you provided is that the one didn't have a `p` tag it was inside of a `td` which "plays" a little better when using vertical align.

Comment: The `line-height` thing works in browsers but not after I turn the  HTML file into an Outlook email. :(

Comment: remove the p tag and add the styles to the parent `td`